InstallShield - ISBEW64.exe - InstallShield (R) 64-bit Setup Engine running forever in background
I got a problem with my window app which was created by InstallShield 2022.
When I press to "Finish" button, this dialog is closed as expected.

However, the ISBEW64.exe is opened and running in the background.

This is the reason I got the popup below when try to click again to uninstall my application.

This problem still happened until I killed the ISBEW64.exe by the task manager.
The question here Do I miss anything with InstallShield? Is there any way to automatically end the uninstall process?
Thanks, everyone.
